# Graphical File Manager for Linux with Fuzzy Search for Navigation

Tags: linux, file-management

I am looking for a feature-rich graphical file manager that supports (native or via plugin) fuzzy search (like fzf) for jumping to other directories.  For example I'd like to press some key to open a dialog where I can enter something like "~/pic23fo" and it will suggest completion to "~/Pictures/2023/foo".

The only one I found so far is fman which looks very promising but it is lacking some other convenient features like thumbnails, easy mounting/accessing of removable drives, etc.  This is also what disqualifies terminal-based file managers for me.

Currently I'm using Dolphin which I'm generally happy with except the lack for the fuzzy goto.

Comment: In case no file manager with this functionality exists, I'd also be happy to know about ones that have nice plugin support to potentially implement it myself.